# List of all BibTex entries in a .bib file, to generate Hakyll publication list?

Tags: haskell, pandoc, bibtex, static-site, hakyll

I'm making a personal website with Hakyll, and I'd like to list my publications.

I've found [this module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.9.5.1/docs/Hakyll-Web-Pandoc-Biblio.html#t:Biblio) and [this guide](https://github.com/mcmtroffaes/homepage/blob/master/posts/2015-01-09-hakyll-and-bibtex.markdown) for how to print the references from a markdown document at the bottom.

The problem with this is, it assumes you've got some document, where you cite all the things you want printed.

What I want is to *generate* a document that lists *every* document my .bib file. In particular:

- I don't want to have to manually write the bibtex name of each publication I want listed
- I just want the "references" section printed, i.e. there's no place in the document where the publication is referenced, they're just listed at the end.

Is it possible to get this information from the `Hakyll.Web.Pandoc.Biblio` module? Or do I need to separately parse the .bib file to get this? And once I do, how would I make go about generating this page with Hakyll?

Comment: You probably can use [pandoc-citeproc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc) to parse the .bib file into YAML or JSON and generate HTML from that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [this trick from the pandoc's manual](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citations), the equivalent of biblatex's `\nocite{*}`:

> It is possible to create a bibliography with all the citations,
>   whether or not they appear in the document, by using a wildcard:
>
> ```
> ---
> nocite: |
>   @*
> ---
> ```